# unable to render objects to html - no error messages

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to render some object data from view - > html. I've managed this for other Django projects, and I am a bit lost why the following is not working. Help is much appreciated!

I am receiving no error in the http response and from as far as i can tell the below should work.. The same objects are displayed in the backend without issue, see last code snippet for that view.

Solved

Typo - below in the html

```
{% 'for val in context'%}
```

did not receive the input from views as it was called context: in the render

```
{'context:' : objects}
```

Thanks all

My html:

```
<div id="home_top_left_inner" class="container-fluid">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% for val in context %}
<p class='white_text'>{{ val }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Views

```
from api.models import general_employee_data

def index(request):
   all_employees = general_employee_data.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'index.html', {'context' : all_employees})
```

If I put a print in  the above view I receive

```
<QuerySet [<general_employee_data: chang, ko-lin - portal id: ki5s0r3ab>, 
<general_employee_data: 
test, test - portal id: 19eohz4gy>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p class='white_text'>{{ val }}</p>
```

**remove class='white_text'**

If the background is white, do not use the white text colour.